# How to know that my data is Skewed?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

After transferring my data (suppose table) to HDFS, I have no idea how my data is replicated (which part goes to which machne (node)).

So, running Spark SQL queries some people say that you can give hint to spark that my data is skewed.

But how would i know that my data is skewed so i can give hint to spark?

Comment: Can use glom method to see each partition count on spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you load the data in any distributed system like HDFS you load it w.r.t partition key. In this scenario if for one of the partition key value you have more number of records compared to other values then your data is not evenly distributed. Most of the times spark will work well even if your data is slightly skewed but for example in one partition value you have 90% of the data and another has 10% then it will be a challenge for large dataset. Your one task will do more job compared to another and spark will be stuck in one task. So data analysis is important factor

In order to handle data Skegness either you need to partition the data evenly or you will use iterative broadcast join. There is an excellent article from Databricks in this. Please check Databricks with the text iterative broadcast join.

————————-

By default a partition is created for one block of HDFS. By default it’s 128 MB . While reading from the spark if you are not going to provide any parameter for the parallelism then it will create one task for each block. So take  an example you have 4 cores and partition is 5. and each partition takes 10 mins approx. so  4 cores will work on 4 partition in parallel and complete in 10 mins. Then last partition will be completed in next 10 mins once it will be taken up by one free core. So more partition is not also good. In case of less partitioning the parallelism will be less and data skewing might happen if most of your data resides in one partition and one task will do more work than the other.

Comment: Hello Chandan, that i understand, now what happens when i have no partitions, in that case there is no problem of Skewed data?

Comment: I have added few more points on my answer after the line please check

Comment: 128Mb is the new default block size.

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on your data qualities and how do you want to use those data. Also, depends on your Spark how to implement the algorithms. Basically, you can use SQL to make some query pick one of the columns as key for example user_name. id so on, and make a group by seeing if there have huge differences.

```
For example if have such case 
select count(distinct(user_name)) from your table group by user_id 

count           username 
199999999999      abc123
12                abc124
6                 abc121
```

Check the example above, the username abc123 which is data skew problem.

There have few references regarding resolve the data skew problem in Apache Spark
1.http://silverpond.com.au/2016/10/06/balancing-spark.html
2.https://databricks.com/session/handling-data-skew-adaptively-in-spark-using-dynamic-repartitioning